# Why does coalesce() in R return extra values for me?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to use `coalesce()`. An example dataset looks like this (reproducible code is below that):

```
    Country X2016 X2017 X2018
1 Australia    10    NA    12
2        UK    15    20    NA
3       USA    NA    40    NA
```

When I pass two vectors in this form: `coalesce(df$X2018, df$X2017)`, it works fine.

But when I put the vectors in as: `df[4], df[3]`, I get unexpected extra values.

Reproducible example below:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 Country = c("Australia", "UK", "USA"),
                 X2016 = c(10L, 15L, NA),
                 X2017 = c(NA, 20L, 40L),
                 X2018 = c(12L, NA, NA)
)
df
coalesce(df$X2018, df$X2017)
coalesce(df[4], df[3])
```

So `coalesce(df$X2018, df$X2017)` returns:

```
[1] 12 20 40
```

which is as expected.

What I don't understand is why `coalesce(df[4], df[3])` returns:

```
       X2018
1         12
2 NA, 20, 40
3 NA, 20, 40
```

I can't figure out why it's returning the first two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `df[4]`, you are actually referring to a *data frame* (or, more generally, a list).  This is what is throwing off the `coalesce` function.  You probably were intending to do this:

```
coalesce(df[[4]], df[[3]])
```

As to *why* you are seeing your current output, we might have to look into the exact implementation of `coalesce`.

Comment: For anyone looking at this question in the future, in addition to Tim Biegeleisen's excellent answer, I also found this link very useful, to work out the details:

[http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html]